# iOS 13 UIViewController modal presentation shadow

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios13

I have modaly presented view controller in iOS >=13. Root view has clear background:

```
view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Child view with white background has some top offset like this:

[image]

All is ok, but when I try to dismiss it by swipe down I see slightly visible shadow of presented view controller:

[image]

Is it posible to remove this shadow on modal presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Upon further investigation, this does not appear to be something that can be changed. It's a private UIKit View setup by iOS and is a new addition in iOS 13. See 19:50 at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/

For my own apps/games I'll be looking to create a custom UIModalPresentationStyle to achieve the look I want.

You can also alleviate from this by simply presenting as .fullScreen or another presentation style instead of this new sheet method.

---

<del>I have been trying to find the answer to this myself. So far I have only found that by setting the layer.shadowColor to clear it fixes this but only on iPhone. I cannot find how to fix this on iPad. 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    }</del>

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried that for iPhone on ios 13, not working for me.

Comment: Is there anyway of "subclassing" the already made UIModalPresentationStyle and simply remove that shadow?

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for you

```
extension UIViewController {
    func removeBackgroundForParents() {
        var superview = view.superview
        while superview != nil {
            superview?.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            superview?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            superview = superview?.superview
        }
    }
}
```

And use it in your view controller.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    removeBackgroundForParents()
}
```

Comment: this seems a bit too 'hacky' but it's the only solution i guess. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the sources of the view controller in question (say it's closed-source 3rd party) possibly a better hack would be to find a superview of class UIDimmingView and hide it.

```
private extension UIView {

    func removeDimming() {
        if let dim = subviews(ofClass: "UIDimmingView").first {
            dim.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            superview?.removeDimming()
        }
    }

    func subviews(ofClass name: String) -> [UIView] {
        subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == name } +
            subviews.flatMap { $0.subviews(ofClass: name) }
    }
}
```

Then in your view controller's overridden `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

```
@_dynamicReplacement(for: viewDidLayoutSubviews)
func sub_viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    view.superview?.removeDimming()
}
```